# alfresco javascript watermark image compression

Tags: javascript, alfresco, watermark

I use the watermark from pdf toolkit in alfresco, the script (javascript) for adding an image in a pdf works fine. The only problem is that the image in the pdf is blur and not as good as the original image.
I guess there is a compression or something but can't figure out which option will let me adjust that compression.
I tried different source but every time the final result is not good
        `watermark_action.parameters["inplace"] = true;
        watermark_action.parameters["destination-folder"] = document.parent;
        watermark_action.parameters["watermark-type"] = "image";
        watermark_action.parameters["watermark-image"] = dest_folder;
        watermark_action.parameters["page"] = "first";
        watermark_action.parameters["watermark-depth"] = "under";
        watermark_action.parameters["position"] = "manual";
        watermark_action.parameters["location-x"] = "-20";
        watermark_action.parameters["location-y"] = "700";
        watermark_action.execute(pdf_to_watermark);`

Comment: Please provide the code you have already tried.

Comment: The code works fine it's just the quality of the image that is not good after watermarking probably due to some compression

Comment: Without seeing the code, we don't have a lot of hope of telling you what's being done wrong...

Comment: well I add the code but I just miss an option, the code works fine

Comment: What is the file type and size of the image you are using for your watermark?

Comment: it's a jpeg, I tried with several "quality" the size was from 12ko to 40ko

Comment: Check watermark aspect ratio. Try to use tiff format. Can you share with us watermark image and result pdf? Here is the source code: https://github.com/ntmcminn/alfresco-pdf-toolkit/blob/master/pdf-toolkit-repo/src/main/java/org/alfresco/extension/pdftoolkit/service/PDFToolkitServiceImpl.java